# Почему функция onOffsetChanged не работает с асинхронной загрузкой из БД?

Tags: java, android

Задумка элементарная, скрывать `fab` если `appbar` в скрытом состоянии. Добавил `onOffsetChanged` для отслеживания состояния `appbar`. В активности имеется `layout` в нем находится пара `TextView` и кнопка которая переводит вьюхи в состояние `GONE`. Почему скрытие `fab` происходит только когда `TextView`-хи в скрытом состоянии, а в случае когда они `VISIBLE` функция скрытия `fab`-а никак не реагирует? Опытным путем понял, что проблема в коде асинхронной загрузки данных из БД, если отключить загрузку и оставить пустые `TextView` скрытие `fab`-а работает правильно и в случае скрытых вью, и в случае видимых. Хочу заметить, что если прокрутить экран и скрыть `appbar` при видимых `TextView` `fab` не исчезнет, но если в том же состоянии нажать кнопку и скрыть `TextView`-хи то `fab` тут же скрывается. Никак не могу понять суть, что же мешает выполнению кода , ведь мешает просто асинхронная загрузка из БД, которая, по сути, не должна как-то влиять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    DataBase db;

SharedPreferences pref;
public static final String APP_F = "f" ;
boolean set1; // переменная состояния открытости/закрытости блока
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 0;

TextView num_1;
TextView item1;
float num1;
FloatingActionButton fab;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);

    db = new DataBase(this);
    db.open();

    item1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_add);
    num_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_1);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

        }
    });

    if (!pref.getBoolean(APP_F, set1))
    {
        item1.setVisibility(GONE);
        num_1.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    hideFab();

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(1).forceLoad();
}

public void set_max_min (View view)
{
    if (item1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        item1.setVisibility(GONE);
        num_1.setVisibility(GONE);
        set1 = false;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(APP_F, set1);
        editor.apply();
    }
    else
    {
        item1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        num_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        set1 = true;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(APP_F, set1);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

//Блок кода асинхронной загрузки данных из БД

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bnd)
{
    return new MyLoader(this, db, id);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
{
    switch (loader.getId())
    {
        case 1:
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(1).forceLoad();
                   if (cursor.moveToLast())
                   {
                       num1 = cursor.getFloat(0);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       num1 = 0;
                   }
                String n1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.0").format(num1);
                num_1.setText(n1);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
{

}

static class MyLoader extends CursorLoader
{
    DataBase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    final int LoaderID;

    public MyLoader (Context context, DataBase db, int id)
    {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LoaderID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground()
    {
        switch (LoaderID)
        {
            case 1:cursor = db.last_add();
                break;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}

public void hideFab ()
{
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset)
        {
            if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange())
            {
                fab.animate()
                        .scaleX(0f)
                        .scaleY(0f)
                        .start();
            }

            else if (verticalOffset == 0)
            {
                fab.animate()
                        .scaleX(1f)
                        .scaleY(1f)
                        .start();
            }

            else
            {
                fab.animate()
                        .scaleX(0.3f)
                        .scaleY(0.3f)
                        .start();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в вызове `getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(1).forceLoad();` в `onLoadFinished`. `Forceload` принудительно зацикливал загрузку данных из БД, что мешало выполнению кода скрывающего `fab`.
Правильно вызывать `getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(1)`, а `Forceload` в случае когда нужно обновить данные